# read wowza stream in vlc player

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I have the following info for a stream:

- page url: http://www.liveduvalstreet.com/
- stream url: "http://wowza2.floridakeysmedia.com:8090/liveduvalstreet/liveduvalstreet.stream/manifest.f4m"
- swf url: http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback_101.swf
- from URLhelper: http://wowza2.floridakeysmedia.com:8090/liveduvalstreet/liveduvalstreet.stream/media_b103328_w2047992354.abst/Seg1-Frag13699 (says its an .mp4 video)

is it possible to play this stream in vlc player? thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open this (HLS) URL in VLC: http://wowza2.floridakeysmedia.com:8090/liveduvalstreet/liveduvalstreet.stream/playlist.m3u8

Comment: That link works! Now if I have more links like that I will replace manifest.f4m with playlist.m3u8. thank you.